# MySQL Row to four Column

Tags: php, mysql, row

can any one help me on how can I create a query output using the row data on the source table as a header on my output. Please see below for illustration.

E.G.

Row Data:

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| colHeader | value     | no        | price     |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| Header1   | value 1   | no 1      | price1    |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| Header1   | value 2   | no 2      | price2    |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| Header2   | value 1   | no 3      | price3    |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| Header2   | value 2   | no 4      | price4    |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

Output:

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| colHeader | value 1 no| value 2 no|value1price|value2price|
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| Header1   | no 1      |    no 2   |price1     |   price2  |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| Header2   | no 3      |    no 4   |price3     |   price4  |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

Is it possible?? I want print it through the PHP

Thank you.

Comment: Not sure with query, but (_love this line_) can be done with PHP.

Comment: @OP can you explain where you are getting the value `value 1 no` in your output? Is it `value 1`? Also, I can assume `Header1` may repeat more than two times?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select
colHeader,
max(case when value = 'value 1' then no else null end) as value1,
max(case when value = 'value 2' then no else null end) as value2,
max(case when value = 'value 1' then price else null end) as value1price,
max(case when value = 'value 2' then price else null end) as value2price
from
your_table
group by colHeader
```

- see it working live in an <kbd>[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/61014/2/0)</kbd>

Executing the query in multiple steps is hopefully self explaining (added some notes, though):

```
select
*
from
t;
```

Result:

```
| COLHEADER |   VALUE |   NO |  PRICE |
|-----------|---------|------|--------|
|   Header1 | value 1 | no 1 | price1 |
|   Header1 | value 2 | no 2 | price2 |
|   Header2 | value 1 | no 3 | price3 |
|   Header2 | value 2 | no 4 | price4 |
```

---

```
select
colHeader,
case when value = 'value 1' then no else null end as value1,
case when value = 'value 2' then no else null end as value2,
case when value = 'value 1' then price else null end as value1price,
case when value = 'value 2' then price else null end as value2price
from
t;
```

Result:

```
| COLHEADER | VALUE1 | VALUE2 | VALUE1PRICE | VALUE2PRICE |
|-----------|--------|--------|-------------|-------------|
|   Header1 |   no 1 | (null) |      price1 |      (null) |
|   Header1 | (null) |   no 2 |      (null) |      price2 |
|   Header2 |   no 3 | (null) |      price3 |      (null) |
|   Header2 | (null) |   no 4 |      (null) |      price4 |
```

---

Not sure if the following step isn't more confusing than anything else. It returns the rows "collapsed" by column colHeader. That is, that a random row per group is displayed (in this case every second row is omitted), if no aggregate function like `max()` is used. Note, that this is not standard SQL and that if I'm not mistaken only MySQL allows this. Anyway, that's the reason, why we use the `max()` function in the last step.

```
select
colHeader,
case when value = 'value 1' then no else null end as value1,
case when value = 'value 2' then no else null end as value2,
case when value = 'value 1' then price else null end as value1price,
case when value = 'value 2' then price else null end as value2price
from
t
group by colHeader;
```

Result:

```
| COLHEADER | VALUE1 | VALUE2 | VALUE1PRICE | VALUE2PRICE |
|-----------|--------|--------|-------------|-------------|
|   Header1 |   no 1 | (null) |      price1 |      (null) |
|   Header2 |   no 3 | (null) |      price3 |      (null) |
```

---

Final step:

```
select
colHeader,
max(case when value = 'value 1' then no else null end) as value1,
max(case when value = 'value 2' then no else null end) as value2,
max(case when value = 'value 1' then price else null end) as value1price,
max(case when value = 'value 2' then price else null end) as value2price
from
t
group by colHeader;
```

Result:

```
| COLHEADER | VALUE1 | VALUE2 | VALUE1PRICE | VALUE2PRICE |
|-----------|--------|--------|-------------|-------------|
|   Header1 |   no 1 |   no 2 |      price1 |      price2 |
|   Header2 |   no 3 |   no 4 |      price3 |      price4 |
```

Comment: @ICanHasCheezburger Expanded my answer, hope it's understandable now.

Comment: Very well explained! I'll try to post a PHP solution too.